# SELECT query to select based on number of rows

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite

I have a requirement where I want to run a SELECT query with a where clause and group by. It returns few rows out of which I want to pick the rows which are least in number.

Example:

```
table t1:
host_name   application  type  
host1        app1         0
host2        app2         0
host3        app4         0
host1        app5         0
host2        app6         0
host1        app7         1
host2        app8         1
```

In the above table i want to get the host which is least loaded.

**host1** runs `app1`, `app5`, `app7`.

**host2** runs `app2`, `app6`, `app8`.

**host3** runs `app4` only.

so host3 is least loaded. When I run the query, the output should be "host3". Rows of `type=0` only must be chosen.

I have solution. But is it optimized ? is there a best optimized way to achieve this ?

```
SELECT host_name from (SELECT host_name, min(count) FROM (SELECT host_name, COUNT(*) as count FROM t1 where type=0 group by host_name) as Dup ORDER BY host_name);
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: do you always need 1 row?

Comment: Yes I need a single row with host name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, it will return least `host` by number of `apps`:

```
select `host_name` 
from t1
where type = 0
group by `host_name`
order by count(`host_name`) ASC
limit 0,1
```

Comment: Thanks..This helps.

Comment: This one is optimized too. Thank you very much.